# KendoUI: TabStrip Content loading a partial that accesses the model from the parent

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui

I've got a Tabstrip in KendoUI MVC, and I'm trying to load in content from partials. The partials need to access the model from the encapsulating view. I've been bashing my head against this for about an hour.

Here's what I've got:

```
@model NewAcctForms.Kendo.Models.VSInstModel

...

items.Add()
  .Text("Account Information")
  .Enabled(true)
  .Content(Html.Partial("NewAccountPartials/AccountInformation",NewAcctForms.Kendo.Models.VSInstModel).ToHtmlString());
```

And this is the compiler error that's coming back:

> CS0119: 'NewAcctForms.Kendo.Models.VSInstModel' is a 'type', which is not valid in the given context

Can anyone please point me in the right direction here? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first line defines the Model type. You can then reference it using Model.

```
.Content(Html.Partial("NewAccountPartials/AccountInformation",Model).ToHtmlString());
```

Actually, given that you are passing the model to the partial view, you probably should use:

```
.Content(Html.Action("AccountInformation","NewAccountPartials", Model));
```

Comment: Thanks Andrew! I think this got me past this original error, but I'm now receiving another compiler error, this one generated by the view:  `CS0103: The name 'AccountOwnershipType' does not exist in the current context` Any idea how I can avoid this?

Comment: 'AccountOwnershipType' isn't mentioned anywhere in your orgininal question, I'm assuming it is in the model. If you start a new question with your view and model I'll take a look at it.
If the above answer fixed your original problem can you please mark it as the answer, Thanks.

Comment: Definitely -- you certainly answered my original question, and I was able to resolve this other error which was unrelated. Thanks for humoring and helping an ASP.NET MVC newbie. :)